# DSpace version 4.x Adding Facet, which messages.xml file should I edit?

Tags: facet, discovery, dspace

After editing Discovery.xml located in C:\dspace-4.2-release\dspace\config\spring\api to add facet, which messages.xml should be edited to add a key,

```
<message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.type">Type</message
```

because I realized there are 10 messages.xml files in C:\dspace-4.2-release folder. Does anyone know which messages.xml should I add the key? This is for XMLUI Interface.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is for xmlui interface.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following facet

```
 <bean id="searchFilterCourse"
    class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.HierarchicalSidebarFacetConfiguration">
    <property name="indexFieldName" value="course"/>
```

Here is the pattern that I follow for providing message text for the facet.

```
<message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.AdvancedSearch.type_course">Course</message>
<message key="xmlui.Discovery.AbstractSearch.type_course">Course</message>
<message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.course">Course</message>
```

Comment: My site is not multi-lingual, so I only update messages.xml within mdoules/xmlui/src/main/java/webapp/i18n

Answer (score 1):

This is the file you need to edit:

```
[dspace-source]/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/i18n/messages.xml
```

This is where you should store & manage it in your src tree:

```
[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/webapp/i18n/
```

After editing, rebuild with mvn and redeploy.

source:

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Localization+L10n#LocalizationL10n-XMLUIspecificlocalization