# Want to add custom filter type in dspace 4.x search filter facet

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace

I am using dspace 4.x XMLUI version. I want to add new filter type like "Type of Learning Material","Education Level"etc. in the discovery search filter list(not in sidebar facet). How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [dspace-install-dir]/config/spring/api/discovery.xml, you can add your custom search filter. For example, if you want to add a search filter for dc.type, you should add:

```
<bean id="searchFilterType" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilterFacet">
    <property name="indexFieldName" value="type"/>
    <property name="metadataFields">
        <list>
            <value>dc.type</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="type" value="text"/>
    <property name="sortOrder" value="VALUE"/>
</bean>
```

and then add:

```
<ref bean="searchFilterType" />
```

to the existing searchFilters, e.g.:

```
        <list>
            <ref bean="searchFilterTitle" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterType" />
        </list>
```

Make sure to add this in the

```
<bean id="homepageConfiguration" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfiguration" scope="prototype">
```

if you have this entry

```
<entry key="site" value-ref="homepageConfiguration" />
```

in your

```
<bean id="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfigurationService" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfigurationService">
```

> After modifying sidebarFacets and searchFilters, don't forget to
>   reindex existing items by running [dspace]/bin/dspace index-discovery
>   -b, otherwise the changes will not appear.

Please read [Search filters & sidebar facets Customization](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Discovery#Discovery-Searchfilters&sidebarfacetsCustomization) in the documentation for additional details.

**UPDATE**

To apply your own label for the searchFilters, edit your `[dspace-install-dir]/webapps/xmlui/i18n/messages.xml`.
Example:

```
    <message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.type">Type</message>
```

Please note that to ensure that your custom messages are not overwritten the next time you rebuild, you should store & manage it in your src tree:
`[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/webapp/i18n/`
 which is mentioned [here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Localization+L10n#LocalizationL10n-XMLUIspecificlocalization).

Comment: I think, to do it completely successful, we have to modify some 'messages.xml' file. Can anyone help me to find those 'messages.xml' file?

Comment: I'm actually expecting that you will ask this:) Please see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556499/dspace-version-4-x-adding-facet-which-messages-xml-file-should-i-edit), I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have done all things that you have said, now the newly added items are showing in search filter list but in this format-> "xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.typeoflm". But i want to show it -->  "Type of Learning Material".
I have done all changes in installation folder,not in source.

Comment: Did you try to restart your tomcat and clear your browser cache? Also, don't forget to run index-discovery -b after you modify your discovery.xml. Sometimes, all it takes for your new messages to appear is a **hard** restart/refresh of the browser. Did you add this `<message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.typeoflm">Type of Learning Material</message>` to your messages.xml?